# Implicit equation plotting

Tags: plot, equation, implicit

I’m not a python expert, just a beginner, I would like to know how I could code and plot the equation shown here by using the implicit equation option??. This is my attempt but not sure how to plot it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
k = 1.380649e-23
T = 1.2e6
mH = 1.66e-27
G = 6.67e-11
Ms = 1.99e30
uc = sqrt(2 * k * T/mH)
rc = G * Ms * mH/4 * k * T
(u/uc)^2 - 2 * log(u/uc) == 4 * log(r/rc) + 4 * log(rc/r) - 3
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXCbH.png)